# Waterflow / Watercooling Question

Tags: fluid-dynamics, potential-flow

This is probably a very basic question, but I was not really sure how to look it up.
I am thinking of watercooling some CPUs with one loop. I can either create one loop with T-Connectors (green design) or use distribution plates (red). Also a mix (distro in, T out, etc) would be possible. How do I get (more or less) the same flow on every CPU or would that be the same result with either approach?

[image: T Connection VS Distro]

**EDIT:** The right approach seems to be the Tichelmann System - I hope I got it right.
[image: Tichelmann System?]

Two routing are possible - from what I understand the RED arrow would be better/closer to the correct layout then the green one.

Comment: How do the distribution plates work?

Comment: pretty simple; it's a container with N outlets. One is connected to the pump which pushes the water into the others. no distribution, balancing, etc

Comment: if it matter; this layout might be vertical (CPUs are on top of each other, not on the same level). Might also add CPUs above the Pump - but I assume it does not matter for this topic.

Comment: I have two more questions.  Can you monitor the temperature of the CPU's?  Also, do small valves exist for the tubing that you plan to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the assembly on the left (green diagram), the length of the piping of each circuit feeding a CPU from the branching is different from the other circuits which causes a different linear and singular pressure drop* (resistance**), therefore a different flow without regulation in each CPU, the same observation for the assembly on the right (red) except if the piping of each circuit is equal, there is a loop which equalizes the pressure drops (i.e. the flow) called loop or Tichelmann system***.

*https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_drop

**https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_analogy

***https://second.wiki/wiki/tichelmann-system

Comment: To get it straight, the green one is roughly a Tichelmann-system and therefore even superior to the Red one? Or least isn't inferior.

Comment: Sorry,  the green system is not a Tichelmann-system  because it needs 3 pipes, the third to balance the pressure drops:  it must be connected to the last cpu (the farthest), a single T.

Comment: Last one (I hope) - I added another schema. The Red Arrow would be a parallel Tichelmann and closed to even distribution then the serial one - right? CPUs are probably place horizontal to each other (rack).

Comment: Perfect, the idea is that the length of the pipe from the start to the return of the manifolds is the same for each component of the circuit .(~ same pressure drop => same flow) 
 https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boucle_de_Tichelmann#/media/Fichier:SolarThermie_Tichelmann.svg